# NullReferenceException when creating new site collection

Tags: administration, site-collection, content-database

Running a SharePoint 2010 farm. Whenever I attempt to create a new site collection I get the following error "Object reference not set to instance of an object" which is generated from a generic NullReferenceException. This occurs regardless of what interface I use to create it (central administration, powershell, stsadm).

Here is the stack trace from the logs:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabaseCollection.FindBestContentDatabaseForSiteCreation(IEnumerable`1
>   contentDatabases, Guid siteIdToAvoid, Guid webIdToAvoid,
>   SPContentDatabase database, SPContentDatabase
>   databaseTheSiteWillBeDeletedFrom)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabaseCollection.FindBestContentDatabaseForSiteCreation(SPSiteCreationParameters
>   siteCreationParameters, Guid siteIdToAvoid, Guid webIdToAvoid,
>   SPContentDatabase database, SPContentDatabase
>   databaseTheSiteWillBeDeletedFrom)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabaseCollection.FindBestContentDatabaseForSiteCreation(SPSiteCreationParameters
>   siteCreationParameters)

I assume this is caused by a broken content database that is referred to but does not actually exist. Has anyone encountered this problem before? Is there a way to detect and remove orphaned or broken database references without combing through the configuration database?

Answer (score 2):

There is a null reference associated with the web application; the steps for removal are here:

http://mydailytechlog.blogspot.com/2011/12/sp2010-cannot-create-new-site.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what can be the cause, but first I would check if both, the application pool user and the timer job user, have the proper permissions on all of the content databases.

Also [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/21/10014116.aspx) is similar issue. Exception there occurs while restoring a site collection, but maybe it will give You some hint...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article it covers various reasons and resolutions why this issue may occur 
http://sp-vinod.blogspot.com/2012/02/cannot-create-site-collection-error.html

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint! While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer] for general guidelines.